# facebook login with 2 accounts iOS SWIFT

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an app, where users can buy things from each others.
 I'm trying to login with 2 different Facebook accounts to test the app.

Problem:

When I log in with the first one everything works fine, then I logout and try to login with the second Facebook account once I press login button it displays the authorisation of the first account, I can reset simulator however it will delete the first account details from core data, I want to be able to login with the second Facebook account with keeping the first Facebook account details in core data , I appreciate your help .. please help with link or the logic of doing so

Comment: Thanks brian for fixing my paragraph by changing i to I , however i would like a solution to my problem instead :) regards

Comment: I would suggest to include some code of your implementation detail, so others can look at it.